# Padding string in C with sprintf and #define constant

Tags: c, gcc, printf, clang

Let's say I have a `#define` directive defining an integer:

```
#define ZEROPADDING 20
```

Is there a way to use that constant with `sprintf()` to zero-pad a string?

Currently I do this, which contains a "magic number":

```
size_t my_string_length = 0;
/* append some stuff to my string... */
/* append string length to my string, for example */
my_string_length += sprintf(my_string + my_string_length, "%020zu", strlen(my_string));
```

I'd like to replace that with something like:

```
my_string_length += sprintf(my_string + my_string_length, "%0ZEROPADDINGzu", strlen(my_string));
```

Or:

```
my_string_length += sprintf(my_string + my_string_length, "%0"ZEROPADDING"zu", strlen(my_string));
```

But the compiler is saying I can't do this.

I'd like to avoid using "magic numbers". Is there an idiom in C for using `#define` directives in this way, or do I need to write a custom function to zero-pad with a padding width known only at runtime?

Comment: I think you can define ZEROPADDING "20", instead of 20, then use the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_string_length += sprintf(my_string + my_string_length, "%0*zu",
    (int)ZEROPADDING, strlen(my_string));
```

I used a cast to `int` since the `*` width/precision special always requires `int`, and bad things could happen if the argument happened to have a different integer type. In your case (20) you don't need it, but it doesn't hurt.

As an aside, you should never use `sprintf`; use `snprintf` instead.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why should I never use `sprintf`?

Comment: `sprintf` has no protection against writing beyond the end of the pointed-to buffer object. While purely numerical formats are *relatively* safe, some of them have locale-specific behavior that could result in more data being written than you expect. Or, your program might get ported to a system where `size_t` is larger and your assumed max number of digits for `size_t` is no longer correct. There are lots of things that can go wrong, and all it takes is one to make your program dangerous. `snprintf` on the other hand is always safe as long as the buffer size argument you pass is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The last is closest.  If you add a macro like

```
#define QUOTED(n) #n
```

and use that

```
my_string_length += sprintf(my_string + my_string_length,"%0" QUOTED(ZEROPADDING) "zu", strlen(my_string));
```

the macro quotes its parameter (using the `#` operator), making it a string.

Comment: I get the following warning from your approach: `warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'unsigned long'`

Comment: It's not the closest.

Comment: As I read the question, the problem was how to put the symbol into the format.  The third example was closest in syntax (types are a different matter).